# Parse Visual Studio Push Notifications

Tags: ios, windows, visual-studio, parse-platform

I am developing an application for one our customers who run a restaurant chain. I want to create a windows form based program so they can send their own push notifications as and when they want. The app is native to iOS with an android version in the pipeline.

Is it possible to do this? (Create a windows from program to send push notifications using Parse SDK)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems extremely possible, as long as you are using the Parse SDK in the Mobile Apps. You can set the app's to subscribe to a "channel(s)" for instance a channel for each restaurant based on location etc.

Then using the .NET SDK you can send a Notification. The way Parse appears to deal with Push Notifications is the device sends a request to the server, which forwards it along to the relevant PNS.

More info can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/.NET)

Comment: Thank you - managed to do this in a test environment and is working like a dream!